# html2canvas - append canvas then remove previous

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors, html5-canvas, html2canvas

I'm using html2canvas to take a 'screenshot' of my window, which I then append to the window as a faint overlay, and then this slowly fades out when you start scrolling. Then again when you stop scrolling, screenshot is appended, and fades out again on scroll start. The idea is if you're scrolling and stopping often you'll build up faint layers which will each be fading out in their own time.

All going well so far. I have managed to fire image capture event multiple times on stop scroll, but am not able to target just one canvas (the most recent) to fadeout on start scroll. My code fades out all canvases together, and then entirely removes the canvas so that I can't fire the stop scroll image capture event again.

Alternatively I could use one event -start scroll- to both append new screenshot and fadeout previous screenshot in one go, but still cannot figure out how to target each.

This is my code for the overlay of screenshots:

```
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");

$.fn.scrollEnd = function(callback, timeout) {          
    $(this).scroll(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.data('scrollTimeout')) {
          clearTimeout($this.data('scrollTimeout'));
        }
        $this.data('scrollTimeout', setTimeout(callback,timeout));
    });
};


$(window).scrollEnd(function(){
alert('stopped scrolling');

    html2canvas(document.body, {canvas: canvas, allowTaint:true,})
    .then(function(canvas) {
        console.log('Drew on the existing canvas');
    });

}, 1000);
```

This is my code for fading out screenshot:

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
var timeout;
return function() {
    var context = this, args = arguments;
    var later = function() {
        timeout = null;
        if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
    };
    var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
  };
};


var scrollingFn = debounce(function() {
$('body').find('canvas').last().delay('4000').fadeOut(10000);
console.log('working');
}, 250, true);

window.addEventListener('mousewheel', scrollingFn);
window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollingFn);
```

I'm not the most fluent in jquery but maybe this is an easy fix for someone who is?